# Cronjob not working

Tags: cron, cronjob

I've got a simple crontab for ripping my local radio station only when I want:

```
0 16 * * 0 /root/streamripper.sh
0 17 * * 0 killall streamripper
0 20 * * 0 /root/streamripper.sh
0 21 * * 0 killall streamripper
```

and it's not working. Also, this is the content of streamripper.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
streamripper http://some.radio.com/stream.aac -s -o never -d /some/secret/directory
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Is streamripper.sh executable (chmod +x /root/streamripper.sh)? Is the streamripper binary in the path? Try to give a full path to it in the script (you get the full path with `which streamripper`).

Answer (score 2):

Worth checking to see if the cron is actually being run - see if the contents of /var/log/cron tie to the expected execution times. Also, is there really any need to mention that the script is probably doing something illegal? -1 for trying to bring down the integrity of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving any error emails?  I'd set MAILTO=some_use_you_read_mail_for and see if there are any obvious errors.

and you don't quite define 'not working'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run as root, then u have to write it like this:

**0 16 * * 0  root /root/streamripper.sh**

U need to tell cron the user **root** so it can properly work

Also make sure the script has the proper rights, so root can execute it, u can check out the right by typing the following command:

**ls -l /some/path/to/script/**

and it should look like this to be executable:

**-rwx**-r--r--

What i highlighted that is what needs to be there.

If the letter x is missing then u should write the following command line:

**sudo chmod u+x /some/path/to/script/name_of_script**

Answer (score 0):

And it makes really no sense to run streamripper as the user *root*. Better use any unprivilegued user for that. For example your own.